# Publish Windows Form application to ftp location

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, publish

I'm using Visual Studio trying to publish my win form app to ftp location so that the users can download it using a link, and later my app could notify the users to update their application.

I have a shared windows website host, I just created a ftp user with full control over a sub-domain. I can access the sub domain successfully using filezill.
but after many hours I can't publish my test win form app. It give me this error

```
Failed to connect to 'ftp://eee.aaa.com/' with the following error:


Unable to create the Web site 'ftp://eee.aaa.com'.  Request denied for policy reasons.
```

what I've been missed?